# How do I connect one function to another in Python battleship game?

Tags: python-3.x

It seems that when the coordinates(ex: 13 45) are entered, it will always be 'Missed' and I think it's because the function gamemode_one() is not linked to the main function print_board(board). The location of the ships is randomly generated. Below are the codes for only Beginner Mode(1).

I would also wish you could give some tips on how to unmask the whole ship when one of its coordinate is hit? (The ships are 5 char long).

```
import random
from random import randint

board = []
board_size = 60

board_top = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

#creating the board
def print_board(board):
    boardHeader=[]
    boardHeader.extend(board_top*6)
    print('    ', end='')
    for i in range(1,7):
        print(str(i).rjust(20), end="")
    print()
    print('    ', end='')
    for i in boardHeader:
        print(str(i).rjust(2), end='')
    print()

    for x in range(20):
        board.append(["#"] * board_size)

    row = 0
    for i in range(len(board)):
       print (str(row + 1).rjust(2), ' ', end = "")
       for j in range(len(board[row])):
           print(board[row][j].rjust(2), end='')
       row +=1
       print()
    return board
print("Let's play Battleship game!")            
print_board(board)

#generate random row and column        
def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
def random_ship(board):
    ship_row = random_row(board)
    ship_col = random_col(board) 
    return ([ship_row, ship_col])

#select game mode
selection = int(input("Select 1 to start or ""Q"" to quit "))    
if selection == 1:
    gamemode = int(input("Select mode: (1)Beginner Mode, (2)Intermediate Mode or (3)Advance  "))
    for i in range(5):
        if gamemode == "1" or gamemode == "2" or gamemode == "3":
            break
        elif gamemode == "q" or gamemode == "Q":
            print ("Sys: That's too bad. Hope to see you soon!")
            exit = True
            break
    else:
        exit

#generate random coordinates according to game mode 1 (Beginner)
def gamemode_one():
    mainShips = []
    for i in range (80):
        tempShips = []
        tempShipRand = random_ship(board)
        ship_row=tempShipRand[0]
        ship_col=tempShipRand[1]
        tempShips.append(tempShipRand)
        for i in range(1,5):
            tempShips.append([ship_row,ship_col+i])

        dup=False
        for i in tempShips:
            for j in mainShips:
                if i in j:
                    dup=True

        if not dup:
            mainShips.append(tempShips)
    return ([ship_row,ship_col])
    return mainShips


#Game mode 1
if gamemode == 1:
    ship_row = gamemode_one()[0]
    ship_col = gamemode_one()[1]
    ships = 1
    booms = 15
    while booms > 0 and ships > 0:
        board=[]
        limit_row=20
        limit_col=60
        guess_row,guess_col = map(int,input("Enter coordinates for row and column: ").split(" "))
        if guess_row==ship_row and guess_col==ship_col:
            print("BOOM!")
            print("O")
            booms -= 1
            ships -= 1
            print("You have", booms, "amount of booms left.")
        elif booms == 0:
            print ("You ran out of booms")
        elif ships == 75:
            game_ends() 
        elif guess_row>limit_row or guess_col>limit_col:
            print("Invalid coordinate!!")
            print("You have", booms, "amount of booms left.")
        else:
            guess_row!=ship_row or guess_col!=ship_col
            print("You missed")
            print(" ")
            booms -= 1
            print("You have", booms, "amount of booms left.")
    print_board(board)



def game_ends():
    if booms >= 13 and booms <= 15:
        print ("You are a novice")
    elif booms >= 10 and booms <= 12:
        print ("Not too bad")
    elif booms < 10:
        print ("You have a talent")
    return
```

Comment: What is the actual indentation on `board.append(["#"] * board_size)`. Is it at the same level as the `for` loop or once more indented?

Comment: @eukaryota it's supposed to be indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always return from `gamemode_one()` via:

`return (9,18)`

There is no randomness.

After edit:

You can easily see that correct random numbers are generated by writing `print(ship_row, ship_col)` after you generate them. You will always get random numbers. However your `board` is of size 60x20 and therefore has 1200 elements. The probability of your guess input to be equal to the random number is therefore about 0.1% and you will need to repeat the guess on average 1200 times to get a hit.

Your whole code is also full of redundancies, unused parts, unnecessary parts and things that just don't make any sense to me. In particular your random numbers to compare to are generated by `ship_row = gamemode_one()[0]` and `ship_col = gamemode_one()[1]`. `gamemode_one` will use the dimensions of the global `board` as limits for the random variable. Its contents are never used beyond the initial `print_board`.

I don't think you understood the concepts behind local and global variables. Just let `board` be a global used by all functions and never pass it around via function argument and return.

Comment: My mistake. I've changed it to return([ship_row,ship_col]), now it is supposed to be randomly generated. But I have no idea why when coordinates are typed, it will always be "Missed".

Comment: @KarenKhoo Updated my answer.